# Does a source exist that expands on skill based healing in low-fantasy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, skills, healing

Given a gritty realism campaign where PC maiming is not entirely uncommon, and the DM frequently introduces situations in which healing magic is unavailable or cannot be used, is there an alternative rule-set or source book than expands upon the heal skill.

**Campaign Background**

The campaign is in a custom world. It is a custom low-fantasy, so while all of the magic stuff is available, the characters generally functioned on a little more than 1/10th the wealth by level as given in the pathfinder SRD.

In more than once instance, he has arranged to strip spellcasting abilities from both the mage(by stealing his spellbook) and cleric(by having something block the characters ability to pray) in the party. The same issue preventing the cleric from regaining spells from their god also prevents channeling positive energy. This means our party loses the ability to heal except through natural means. On some cases, the condition would persist through several character levels. i.e. he would steal the book and block the prayers at the beginning of a dungeon, and would not recover until it was either completed, or nearly so. With the explicit understanding, in the case of the cleric, that he never regain his divine connection with his god unless the he found the source of the interference (permanent until object/character destroyed).

Occasionally, we wound up with a maimed character that could not be treated through basic heal skill as described in 3.5 PHB and pathfinder SRD.

**Questions**

Is there an variant rule available, source-book, that expands upon the heal skill, or introduces other forms of non-magical healing.

The game is primarily 3.5, with some of Pathfinder's elements implemented.

Comment: [Site policy bans game recommendation questions.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/8610) While requesting a list of supplements *is* different from requesting a list of games, a comprehensive list (the only *good* answer) of such products is still shopping. However, the site can accommodate a question that narrows this to a list official Heal skill uses *or* to an assessment of the  game balance of alternative uses of the Heal skill from a product you're considering using.

Comment: @HeyICanChan does the edit help at all? I would ask about specifics outside of the listed references, but I am not aware of any.

Comment: I'd really urge, instead, finding a source for alternatives to healing on [*Drive-thru RPG*](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/index.php) or another similar site, taking a look at it, and then asking questions about it. As it stands, the question's still asking for an endless list. However, asking a *new* question about official means of nonmagical healing available in *D&D 3.5e* is the kind of scavenger hunt some folks around here really go for.

Comment: @HeyICanChan to be honest, that seems to be pretty much what I was looking for, and thought I had communicated. I'm not looking for an entire different system, merely an variant/upgrade for a specific aspect of the tagged system.

Comment: +1 for the link though, did not know about that one